# No videos saved while running Zalenium on windows

Tags: docker, window, zalenium

I started Zalenium server on Windows machine. I am able to run the tests and also see the live execution. But no videos are saved in the shared volume. So I tried SSH to the containers, but no videos are recorded in /home/seluser/video directory.

Below is the command I ran to start zalenium server.

`docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 8083:4444 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /d/docker/:/home/seluser/videos --privileged dosel/zalenium start`

I am able get the contents of /home/seluser/video directory into my D:\docker folder. When I stop the zalenium server, I get lLog message as below:

> -- LOG 11:28:50:150205700 Waiting for 0 mp4 files to be a total of 1...
>
> -- LOG 11:28:53:577890300 WaitForVideosTransferred failed after 40 seconds!

But when I start Zalenium server through Linux Machine I am able to save videos.

Is there any dependency or requirements for video recording?

Thanks for any help or suggestions in advance.

**Below are the Zalenium Logs:**

> docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /d/docker/:/home/seluser/videos --privileged dosel/zalenium start
>
> Docker binary already present, will use that one.                                                                       Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4
>
> -- LOG 07:47:48:727970300 Ensuring docker works...
>
> -- LOG 07:47:48:834945600 Ensuring docker-selenium is available...
>
> haveged: haveged starting up
>
> Copying files for Dashboard...
>
> Starting Nginx reverse proxy...
>
> Starting Selenium Hub...
>
> .........07:47:56.804 [main] INFO  o.o.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3 - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: unknown
>
> 07:47:56.947 [main] INFO  o.o.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3 - Launching Selenium Grid hub on port 4445
>
> ...07:47:57.520 [main] INFO  d.z.e.z.c.DockerContainerClient - About to clean up any left over DockerSelenium containers created by Zalenium
>
> ...07:47:58.266 [AutoStartProxyPoolPoller] INFO  d.z.e.z.proxy.AutoStartProxySet - Starting poller.
>
> ....07:47:59.274 [main] INFO  d.z.ep.zalenium.aspect.HubAspect - Registering custom Zalenium servlets
>
> ..07:47:59.535 [main] INFO  org.openqa.grid.web.Hub - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
>
> 07:47:59.535 [main] INFO  org.openqa.grid.web.Hub - Nodes should register to http://172.17.0.2:4445/grid/register/
>
> 07:47:59.535 [main] INFO  org.openqa.grid.web.Hub - Clients should connect to http://172.17.0.2:4445/wd/hub
>
> Selenium Hub started!
>
> Sauce Labs not enabled...
>
> Browser Stack not enabled...
>
> TestingBot not enabled...
>
> CBT not enabled...
>
> LambdaTest not enabled...
>
> Zalenium is now ready!
>
> *************************************** Data Processing Agreement ***************************************
>
> By using this software you agree that the following non-PII (non personally identifiable information)
>
> data will be collected, processed and used by Zalando SE for the purpose of improving our test
>
> infrastructure tools. Anonymisation with respect of the IP address means that only the first two octets
>
> of the IP address are collected.
>
> See the complete license at https://github.com/zalando/zalenium/blob/master/LICENSE.md
>
> *************************************** Data Processing Agreement ***************************************
>
> 07:48:14.650 [Thread-10] INFO  d.z.e.z.registry.ZaleniumRegistry - Registered a node http://172.17.0.3:40000
>
> 07:48:16.822 [Thread-11] INFO  d.z.e.z.registry.ZaleniumRegistry - Registered a node http://172.17.0.4:40001
>
> 07:49:22.161 [qtp109069556-23] INFO  o.o.g.w.s.handler.RequestHandler - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities {browserName: chrome, platformName: 
>   linux, recordVideo: true}
>
> 07:49:22.165 [qtp109069556-23] INFO  d.z.e.z.registry.ZaleniumRegistry - Adding sessionRequest for {recordVideo=true, browserName=chrome, platformName=linux}
>
> 07:49:22.167 [http://172.17.0.3:40000] INFO  org.openqa.grid.internal.TestSlot - Trying to create a new session on test slot {server:CONFIG_UUID=9bb1cbd4-d32b-4b91-a72d-30900f7fbe99, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, zal:tz=Europe/Berlin, version=78.0.3904.108, platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=true, zal:screenResolution=1920x1080, zal:screen-resolution=1920x1080, browserName=chrome, zal:resolution=1920x1080, maxInstances=1, platformName=LINUX}
>
> 07:49:22.170 [Matcher thread] INFO  d.z.e.z.registry.ZaleniumRegistry - Test session with internal key 7a702dbe-1d2d-46d4-b870-caf43fb11210 assigned to remote (http://172.17.0.3:40000) after 0 seconds (36 ms).
>
> 07:49:49.309 [http://172.17.0.3:40000] INFO  d.z.e.z.p.DockerSeleniumRemoteProxy - Session 7a702dbe-1d2d-46d4-b870-caf43fb11210 completed. Node should shutdown soon...
>
> 07:50:17.406 [Thread-14] INFO  d.z.e.z.registry.ZaleniumRegistry - Registered a node http://172.17.0.3:40002
>
> ^CTrapped SIGTERM/SIGINT so shutting down Zalenium gracefully...
>
> -- LOG 07:51:00:394509900 Waiting for 0 mp4 files to be a total of 1...
>
> -- LOG 07:51:04:482630500 Waiting for 0 mp4 files to be a total of 1...>
>
> -- LOG 07:51:08:544775900 Waiting for 0 mp4 files to be a total of 1...
>
> -- LOG 07:51:12:572234500 Waiting for 0 mp4 files to be a total of 1...
>
> -- LOG 07:51:16:597951000 Waiting for 0 mp4 files to be a total of 1..>>>.
>
> -- LOG 07:51:20:638435000 Waiting for 0 mp4 files to be a total of 1...
>
> -- LOG 07:51:24:694088700 Waiting for 0 mp4 files to be a total of 1...
>
> -- LOG 07:51:28:718235000 Waiting for 0 mp4 files to be a total of 1...
>
> -- LOG 07:51:32:781234600 Waiting for 0 mp4 files to be a total of 1...
>
> -- LOG 07:51:36:829743700 Waiting for 0 mp4 files to be a total of 1...
>
> -- LOG 07:51:40:304254100 WaitForVideosTransferred failed after 40 seconds!
>
> Stopping Hub...
>
> 07:51:40.318 [DockerContainerClient shutdown hook] INFO  d.z.e.z.c.DockerContainerClient - About to clean up any left over DockerSelenium containers created by 
>   Zalenium
>
> 07:51:40.326 [Saving dashboard.] INFO  d.z.ep.zalenium.dashboard.Dashboard - Saving dashboard...
>
> *************************************** Data Processing Agreement ***************************************
>
> By using this software you agree that the following non-PII (non personally identifiable information)
>
> data will be collected, processed and used by Zalando SE for the purpose of improving our test
>
> infrastructure tools. Anonymisation with respect of the IP address means that only the first two octets
>
> of the IP address are collected.
>
> See the complete license at https://github.com/zalando/zalenium/blob/master/LICENSE.md
>
> *************************************** Data Processing Agreement ***************************************

Comment: Does the docker daemon have permissions to write on that Windows directory?

Comment: Yes I have shared the windows drives from docker desktop & I am able to copy all files from /home/seluser/video to the windows directory.  

But in /home/seluser/video folder there is no video present when I ssh into the zalenium container.

Comment: Perhaps you need to share the Zalenium logs as well